# selenium, css: does nth-of-type() work on all browsers?

Tags: css, css-selectors, selenium-rc

I would like to use the following css in my selenium function:

```
nth-of-type()
```

is this supported on all browsers and all versions, or do i need to be careful in using it. 
If so, what all browsers/versions are supported?

thanks

Comment: Does Selenium RC let the browser handle CSS locators?

Comment: i am not sure at all on this. could you please explain

Comment: could you please explain the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted from the [Sauce Labs blog](http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2011/01/why-jquery-in-selenium-css-locators-is-the-way-to-go/):

> For those of you using or willing to use Selenium 2/Webdriver, you may want to re-consider the special Sizzle pseudoclases like :contains or :nth that I’m talking about in this blog post. *For technical reasons, injecting Sizzle in browsers driven by Selenium 2 is not as cheap as with Selenium 1, so the Devs have decided **to rely on the browsers’ implementation of CSS** (standard CSS only) and fallback to Sizzle when needed (in case of old browsers which don’t provide native css selecting for JavaScript).* In Selenium 2 land, my advice, sadly, is to stick to the standard and avoid most of these shortcuts.

So, it is dependent on the browser if you use a recent Selenium version. Use a [CSS support overview site](http://caniuse.com/) to determine it for individual browsers by searching for [the locator you're interested in](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth).

Comment: I am using selenium RC, is that affected too?

Comment: Selenium RC directly drives the browser, so that on will therfore always use the browser's CSS implementation.

Comment: this means i need to be careful while using nth-of-type() for certain browsers even while using selenium RC? Also, if this is a problem, what could i use as a work around for nth-oftype()

Comment: I'd say you know which browsers you want to support before testing your site. If all of them support `nth-of-type`, there is no problem. An alternative is using XPath for these selectors for `<= IE8` browsers. What also could be an option is adding `id` or `class` attributes to the elements that need to be tested.